# Getting javax.mail.MessagingException:connection failure; while searching mails in from 18th folder onwards using JavaMail-IMAP API

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am trying to search all the mails related to a mailId :xxx@gmail.com              from all folders of the mail account's remote server using JavaMailAPI and it's IMAP protocol version:1.5.1,of package:com.sun.mail.imap.

User's Mail account containing 20 folders.While searching for the specific mailId's mail from the folders,precessing properly upto 17 folders.But from 18th         folder onwards getting the Exception as Connection Failure wrap from    CommandFailedException.

Comment: I am getting Exception as follows:
folder15
Found 1 messages in folder15
0
16 folder16
javax.mail.MessagingException: connection failure
connection failure at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.getProtocol(IMAPStore.java:871)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:910)
at com.project.email.IMAPUtil.searchMessagesInFolder(IMAPUtil.java:151)
at com.project.email.test.IMAPTest.main(IMAPTest.java:82)

Can anyone please tell me that :
1)Is there any restriction exist in JavaMail-ImapServer API that to process only upto 17 folders like that? 

Thanks

Comment: There's no restriction in JavaMail, but there may be restrictions in your operating system, your network, or your server.  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show when this happens?  Are you keeping all folders open or do you close each folder as you move on to the next folder?

Comment: Thanks,your information  resolves my issue.